# como juntar botones de redes sociales

Tags: html, css

Soy nuevo en HTML y Tengo varias horas tratando de "juntar" dos botones en donde se redirecciona a las paginas de unas redes sociales, pero quiero que aparezcan los botones uno al lado del otro.

[image: Asi es como me queda]

La imagen de arriba muestra como me queda, cosa que no quiero. Quiero que me quede como la de acontinuación

[image: 2]

De antemano les agradezco

Comment: Te sugiero que cuando hagas preguntas, en lugar de asignar solo imágenes, también muestres parte del código.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me imagino que cada logo ira dentro de una etiqueta , así que puedes darle a cada  la propiedad css float: left, con eso consigues que se pongan un elemento al lado del otro, y con margin-left o margin-right les das espacios a los lados para que no te queden juntos.

Como alternativa te recomiendo que uses Flex, te comento como iría:

**HTML**

```
<div class="contenedor">
<a href="#">Facebook</a>
<a href="#">Instagram</a>
<a href="#">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contenedor{
 display: flex;
}


.contenedor a:not(:last-child){
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Aquí básicamente lo que estas haciendo es alinear los iconos uno al lado del otro, dándoles un margen de 10px a la derecha a todos lo elementos de dentro del contenedor excepto al último

Comment: Gracias alberto, me sirvio demasiado. Logre lo que quería, ya es un problema menos xD

Answer (score 1):

Para poder realizar lo que dices, deberías de meter tus imágenes dentro de un div, si ya están dentro, agregale ya sea una clase o un id y asignale el valor `display: inline-block;` de esta manera tus imágenes deben de quedar como quieres. Ejemplo:

```
div#acostar {
     display:inline-block;
}

<div id="acostar">
    <img....>
    <img....>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto semánticamente hablando, sería:

```css
nav {
  display: flex
}

a {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #ff453a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 5em
}

a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.social {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%
}

.social:hover {
  opacity: .75
}

.messenger {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Facebook_Messenger_logo.svg)
}

.twitter {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/c/c8/Twitter_Bird.svg)
}

.google {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg)
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="messenger social" href="#"></a>
  <a class="twitter social" href="#"></a>
  <a class="google social" href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

Lo que pides, semánticamente hablando es una lista de redes sociales, que básicamente es un elemento `nav`. Utilizarlo mejoraría el ranking del sitio frente a motores de búsqueda como Google o Bing.

Te recomiendo encarecidamente el **uso de imágenes SVG** en vez de PNG.