# Problemas con mi footer

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes para todos!

Tengo una duda con respecto a mi footer.

Lo que en realidad quiero hacer es tener como especie de 3 columnas, en donde la del medio tenga información relevante a la página, en la de la derecha tenga unos botones de redes sociales (ya los tengo) y en la izquierda tambien informacion pero que aun no me suministran y pues aun no he dado con la solucion.

Intente darle el estilo al div contenedor column-count:3; pero no me da el resultado que quiero, que es mas o menos como lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si me ayudan, Gracias!

Comment: utilizas bootstrap?

Comment: Como ya te [habían mencionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262046/como-juntar-botones-de-redes-sociales#comment484570_262046), no uses una imagen y pretendas que adivinemos cuál es tu código a partir de ella. Por favor revisa [mcve]

Comment: L.Ronqullo  no lo utilizo, lo estoy haciendo sin framework, solo CSS.

Comment: Deberías poner tu código como te han comentado. Por otra parte la propiedad `column-count` está pensada para hacer columnas de texto, al estilo de los periódicos, no vas a conseguir con eso el diseño que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 0):

No me ha quedado claro qué necesitas, ya que expones una pregunta cuya respuesta está en la imagen que has proporcionado. En todo caso, responderé tu pregunta:

Una de las cientas de formas de hacerlo es mediante **cajas flexibles**. Tienes el elemento `footer` con tres subelementos, que tendrán la información que quieras que tenga:

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
}

div:first-child {
  background-color: #ff453a
}

div {
  background-color: #28cd41;
  height: 5em;
  width: 100%
}

div:last-child {
  background-color: #0a84ff
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</footer>
```

Te recomiendo tener un orden semántico a la hora de crear un espacio en la web y no mostrar toda la información de una sola vez, porque los motores de búsqueda no podrán contextualizar el sitio.